# Shiny server and shiny apps

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

```
server <- function (input , output  )
{
    output$bar_plot <- renderPlot( 
        {   
            input$click
            inFile <- input$file1
            if (is.null(inFile))
               return(NULL)
            mydata <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)
            resources <-  factor (mydata$Resource.Name)
            stan <-  tapply (mydata$Standard.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
            bil <-  tapply (mydata$Billable.Hours,resources, sum , na.rm=TRUE)
            bu <- bil*100 / stan
            mp <- barplot (bu,col=colors(27),las=2,yaxt="n",ylim=c(0,200),main="Billable      Utilization India-DSI")
            bu<- round(bu,2)
            text(mp, bu,labels=bu, pos = 3)
        }
    )
}
```

This is my server.r code.I have created an action button with input id "click" to generate barplot but the graph is generated directly once I upload the file without clicking on action button.What changes should I make in the code? I tried using eventReactive but result remained the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
shiny server <- function (input, output)
{
  plot <- eventReactive (input $click,
    {
       [code to develop plot]
    }
  )

output$bar_plot <- renderPlot ({ plot () })
}
```